# How to imitate the SELECT COUNT DISTINCT on PromQL in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, distinct, promql

I've been hours trying to imitate the SELECT COUNT DISTINCT on PromQL in Grafana but I'm not able to achieve it.

Let me introduce the following scenario (fictitious, to give an example):

- Imagine I have one metric called `api_interaction` that is incremented each time an external application interacts with my api. Imagine also that this metric has a tag to save the clientId that interacts with this api.So I have:

```
    api_interaction{app="foo", instance="server-1", clientId="123"}  20
    api_interaction{app="foo", instance="server-1", clientId="456"}  20
    api_interaction{app="foo", instance="server-2", clientId="789"}  30
    api_interaction{app="foo", instance="server-2", clientId="123"}  10
```

- Imagine I have another metric called `outside_interaction` that is incremented each time an external application that has interacted with my api requires to access to an external service so my api acts as a bridge. I also have a tag to save the clientId.

```
    outside_interaction{app="foo", instance="server-1", clientId="123"}  2
    outside_interaction{app="foo", instance="server-1", clientId="456"}  1
    outside_interaction{app="foo", instance="server-2", clientId="789"}  3
```

At the end what I want to do is a rate connections to my api / requires external service but  but I find that if I simply divide one metric by the other I will be messing up the data since maybe a customer connects 20 times a day but only one of them requires the external service. So really what I want to do is to do it based on the clientId tag and count for each client tag value only once.

So given the examples above I should have that:
clients 123, 456 and 789 at least connected once and at least required external access once so 3/3 = rate of 100%.

I tried using `count_values("client_id, api_interaction)` promQL method but is not working as expected. It keeps showing lots of values with clientIds I do not recognize and setting them to 1.

Also checked [this documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/) but wasn't able to find what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

count_over_time(api_interaction{app="foo"} == on(clientId) group_left outside_interaction{app="foo"}[1d])

Comment: I understand what you are attempting and seems a good idea. But I think you wrote it worngly. Is giving: bad_data: 1:108: parse error: binary expression must contain only scalar and instant vector types

Comment: Hi @mark04321 could you please correct your suggestion?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).